# General solution to picking x or more balls of one color

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I have $G$ greens balls and $R$ red balls in a single bag.  I select $x$ balls.  What is the probability of selecting $y$ or more green balls assuming $x > y$?

My thinking has been going like this:

1) Ways to select $y$ green balls = $\binom{G}{y}$
2) After selecting $y$ green balls, we must select $(x - y)$ balls of either color from the remaining balls.
3) There are $G+R-y$ balls to select the remaining balls from.
4) There are $\binom{G+R}{x}$ ways to choose $x$ arbitrary balls.

Putting this all together, I get:

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\binom{G}{y} + \binom{G+R-y}{x-y}}{\binom{G+R}{x}}
\end{eqnarray}

Does this look right?

Comment: Your numerator has two problems. First you would multiply those binomial coef's, not add them. But there's a more basic problem with the approach, which is that it doesn't work to pick $y$ greens and then arbitrary $x-y$ others, because you will over-count combinations because e.g. which $y$ many of the greens are in the chosen $y$ sized green group and which ones are in the "arbitrary more $x-y$ balls"?  The simple way to do it is to count the combinations with exactly $y$, exactly $y+1$, ... , exactly min($x,G$) greens, and add those, as in the answer just given below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of selecting exactly $k$ green balls $0\leq k\leq G$ in $x$ draws without replacement is given by
$$
\frac{\binom{G}{k}\binom{R}{x-k}}{\binom{G+R}{x}}
$$
See [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution). Hence the probability of selecting at least $y$ green balls in $x$ draws without replacement is given by
$$
\sum_{k=y}^{\min(x,G)} \frac{\binom{G}{k}\binom{R}{x-k}}{\binom{G+R}{x}}.
$$

Comment: You might need a slight modification if $x<G$, since then the max number of greens to be counted is $x$ not $G$.